# Multithreading of method call (data retrieval from SQL Server) is slower than procedural version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

```
// procedural 
foreach (var foo in bar)
{                                 
    foo.someProperty = getData(ref foo);     
}

// threaded
foreach (var foo in bar)
{                                         
    ThreadStart work = delegate
    {
        getData(ref foo);
    };

   new Thread(work).Start();    
}

getData(ref foo){

    // Either  a LINQ query 

    // Or Exec Command to Stored procedure in SQL Server

    // Either taking approx 2 seconds to return results

    foo.someProperty = resultsFromDBOrLinqStatement;
}
```

If bar had 20 items then simply using the procedural foreach loop takes about 10 seconds - executing one request after another, calling the DB each time.

If, for the same data, the threaded for each loop is used the request takes longer?! It looks like even though the threads are all fine the request to the DB - from each thread - is holding things up.

If i modify the getData() method to;

```
getData(ref foo){

    thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

then, as expected, the entire request is completed in 4 seconds - all threads fire off at pretty much the same time and run concurrently exiting after 4 seconds.

Am i missing something with respect to the DB call in each thread slowing this whole process down? - some web.config setting for concurrent connections to DB etc?

PS. I have tried parallel foreach and Tasks but it always comes back to threading with the database call slowing things down as if the database server is queuing all the calls.

Comment: How do you know that all the threads have finished executing in order to measure the time? In the threaded version of the code you have shown, you are only starting the threads but there's no synchronization point.

Comment: 0.5 secs per bar - pretty slow - guessing that getData is doing a decent amount of SQL - if it's slower in threaded version you've probably got some dead-locking going on

Comment: I currenty have in place a rudimentary monitor (whilst testing) which increments a thread counter on creation of each thread and decrements the counter once each threads call to GetData has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading gives effects when cost of thread creatrion (time, resources) is less than summary of the time of procedural execution.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel requests to a SQL server (or any other database server) will only be faster if *all* of the following conditions are met:

1. The server has one idle processor core for each incoming request (and actually uses one thread per request)
2. Each incoming request involves different files (databases, tables... depending on the actual server)
3. Each batch of files (one per request) lies on it's own HDD
4. The server has enough free physical memory to handle all requests and all involved data simultaneously
5. The server process doesn't run out of memory (not likely, but on 32 bit systems if you request huge amounts of data...)

(If your server has an SSD, point 2 and 3 don't matter - on SSDs the accumulated time for reading multiple files in parallel and sequential is about the same)

In any other case you have only one way to make your program faster (besides getting a faster server, which is not always possible): Make each request itself faster by reducing the work for the server (use stored procedures, cache results in temporary tables, reduce large joins...).